# Need the way to sync corosync.conf in clusters

Tags: pacemaker

I facing problem with conrosync.conf file. I have two node: node1 and node2. corosync.conf in node1 different with corosync.conf in node2. I need the way to sync corosync.conf between two node via bash script. 
Example: if i stand in node 2 and call this script, it will change corosync.conf in node 1 like corosync.conf in node 2. Not allow use some command like:ssh, rsync...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pcs cluster sync can resolve this problem.

```
sync
        Sync corosync configuration to all nodes found from current
        corosync.conf file (cluster.conf on systems running Corosync 1.x)
```